# How to create an alias for opening a directory on Mac

Tags: bash, osx, bash-script

Trying to create an alias `hello`. After typing `hello` in `Terminal`, then `vi` opens `hello_folder`.

Now, this code returns:

```
$ hello 
-bash: hello: command not found 


  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 cd ~/Documents/
  3 
  4 # create directory if it does not exists..
  5 mkdir -p hello_folder
  6 
  7 # in this dir create a dummy hello_file and write something into it.
  8 cd hello_folder
  9 touch hello_file.md && echo 'hello' > hello_file.md.
 10 
 11 # go to ~/.bash_profile and create alias.
 12 # instructions:
 13 # if you type hello in terminal, then it opens hello_folder in vim editor
 14 echo "alias hello='vi /Users/fill_your_username/Documents/hello_folder/'" > ~/.bash_profile
```

What is missing in the code ? - `alias` is not recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the `alias` declaration in `~/.bash_profile` you need to either source that file with `. ~/.bash_profile` or start a new shell. The syntax in your script looks correct, so it should work.

Some extra notes:

1. Note that `echo .... > ~/.bash_profile` will truncate and overwrite the file, it would be safer to append instead, using `>>` like this: `echo .... >> ~/.bash_profile`
2. Instead of `vi /Users/fill_your_username/Documents/hello_folder/` it's better like this: `vi ~/Documents/hello_folder/`
3. When you do `echo 'hello' > hello_file.md.`, there is a `.` at the end, which looks strange, maybe you meant `echo 'hello' > hello_file.md` without a `.` at the end?

Comment: Thanks.Extra `dot` was caused due to settings in my editor.